# How do I keep selection after refresh in datagrid flex?

Tags: database, apache-flex, datagrid

My datagrid is filled with data from an Oracle database. The datagrid refreshes after 1 min. After that, I lose the selected item. I want to avoid that. Consider that it's quite possible that there is new data after refresh, so the selected index may no longer appear in the datagrid after a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say how the DataGrid was being refreshed; whether this is something automatic or something you've built.  But, in essence, do this:

```
// before the refresh
storedSelectedItem = dataGridInstance.selectedItem;

// perform code to do the refresh

// after the refresh
dataGridInstance.selectedItem = storedSelectedItem
```

Comment: Note that flex uses UIDUtil.getUID for testing equality of the selectedItem with the list of items. So make sure to implement IUID if this solution doesn't work as expected.